# Updating parent.parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem. I'm iterating array **ngRepeat = a in arrA** and in this iteration I have nested **ngRepeat b in arrB**. And on selecting **b** a have to update **a** with data from **a**.
Is there proper way to do this?

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="itemA in arrA" >
            <form name="itemForm">
                <ul><li ng-repeat="itemB in arrB"></li></ul>
                <input ng-model="itemA.propName" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So, when I choose **itemB** it should update **itemA.propName**.

Comment: Show some html structure. This could be achievable without parent.parent

Comment: Based on you current update `ng-model="itemA.propName"` should update item from array A, without using my suggested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about you exact scenario but, what you can do is pass the selected item to the function which you want to use to manipulate the object.

```
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="itemA in arrA" >
        <form name="itemForm">
          <ul><li ng-repeat="itemB in arrB"></li></ul>
          <input ng-model="itemA.propName" ng-change="doWork(itemA,itemB)" />
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Now the `doWork` method on the scope would get the selected items of the outer and inner repeat.

Comment: `doWork` will be triggered when user change `input`. But I want to change value of this `input` which I'll get from **itemB**